# How to remove traces of a deleted user

Tags: linux, user-accounts, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have been tasked with removing departed employees' local *nix accounts.  In almost all cases, `userdel -r <username>` works like a charm. However there are a few cases where the user in question was removed uncleanly on a prior date, leaving their account non-existent but with a presence in the /etc/group file and a home directory.  When the task comes to me to remove their user from the system, I find that the user doesn't exist, but I still need to remove these remnants.  In this case, `userdel -r <username>` prints `userdel: user '<username>' does not exist`, and the orphaned group entries, mail spool, home directory etc are not removed.

I could whip up a script to check home, group, and mail spool myself, but I'd rather use an existing utility if it exists.  That utility can be a shell command or an Ansible module.

I'm given the username to purge, and that can be assumed correct, though case insensitivity would be a bonus.  If there's a safe way to find and correct all non-existent users without an input, that would be even better, as it would save me from having to rework previous tasks.

Comment: I've found that I can add the user and then remove them with the -r flag, but that feels somewhat unclean.  It's preferable to writing the script I mentioned in the second paragraph, however.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you need to [delete the user from all his secondary groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74723) with a core utility (on top of userdel)

`usermod -G "" <username> && userdel -r <username>`

You could add it as function to your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` for quicker use

```
nukeusr() {
    usermod -G \"\" $1 && userdel -r $1
}
```

Then `nukeusr <username>` to delete the user from the groups too.

Comment: Actually, `userdel -r <username>` handles removing the user from secondary groups, and that's what I use in the default case.  The issue is when the user has already been deleted without `userdel`'s -r flag.  `usermod` and `userdel` won't work on a user that has been deleted.

Comment: Alright, I didn't understand that from the question. It sounded like `userdel -r` wouldn't work consistently, forgetting the secondary groups sometimes

Comment: Ah, okay. I see how it can be read that way.  I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I believe I would have to delete my reply, right? (reason: unrelated to what you wanted).

I would personaly have gone for your other method : reinstate a dummy user and re-delete it. I could also edit my answer to fit that solution.

Comment: You're free to write up a reply with the dummy user strategy.  I'll probably post it myself if someone doesn't post something cleaner by Monday afternoon.  I realize I posted the question on Good Friday, so I'd like to give it 24 hours that aren't in a holiday weekend.